# flink on k8s How to set the minimum and maximum CPUs

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am using flink on k8s, and now there is a problem, the dynamic resource feature of k8s cannot be utilized, one of my flink tasks only occupies a small amount of CPU resources when it runs normally, but in order for the task to start normally, it is necessary to initially set more CPUs, resulting in a lot of wasted resources, how to set mins and maxs

i am try flink on k8s native and flink operator, only support set cpu min equals max.
There is no way to set them separately

Comment: have you checked [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)? you can define max cpu by defining Kubernetes `limits`

Comment: it does not work, if kubernetes.taskmanager.cpu not set , it is default 1cpu and 1G mem, if set, the min is the same max......

Comment: can you share more information to give better understanding, where are you setting these values? in a helm chart or?

Comment: I am very sorry, I am not very clear, I am currently using flink official flink-kubernetes-operator to submit flink jobs and specify the yaml file, I wrote the code in the answer below, I also tried flink-native way to submit and specify the podTemplate, the result is still the same

Answer (score 0):

just like this, resources limit does not work

```
    apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: basic-reactive-example
spec:
  image: flink:1.17
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  serviceAccount: flink
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: "2048Mi"
              cpu: "2000m"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).